# How to call Apollo Client login method from shared folder inside iOS part of KMM project?

Tags: swift, apollo, apollo-client, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to call the method loginUser from ApolloClient.ks file thats inside the shared folder of Kotlin Multiplatform project. I currently have this code inside the AppoloClient.ks:

```
data class User(val email: String?, val password: String?)

class ApolloClient {
    private val apolloClient = ApolloClient.Builder()
        .serverUrl("http://10.0.2.2:4000/graphql")
        .build()

    suspend fun loginUser(email: String, password: String): User {
        val client = apolloClient
        val response = client.query(LoginUserWithEmailAndPasswordQuery(email = email, password = password)).execute()
        val userEmail = response.data?.loginUser?.email
        val userPassword = response.data?.loginUser?.password
        return User(userEmail, userPassword)
    }
}
```

It works just fine with the Kotlin part of the application (login is working as it should), but when i try to make it work inside ios part i get thread errors. I am new to the whole kotlin multiplatform and none of documentation managed to help me, is there something im missing?

I have tried this

```
import shared 

private var apolloClient = ApolloClient()
```

and then call the method from there like this: apolloClient.loginUser, but i get Thread 1: signal SIGABRT exception

Comment: what kotlin version are you using? since 1.7.20 new memory management model should be enabled by default (unless you've disabled it), and it should solve most of such problems

Comment: @PhilDukhov this is what i have inside the build gradle file: 

    kotlin("android").version("1.7.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.7.10").apply(false)

Comment: I see, I suggest you updating kotlin to latest version - now it's `1.8.10`, or at least to `1.7.20`, which has new memory management model enabled by default. Then your problem will go away. I can't see any obvious problems in your code, but anyway with new MM model you don't have to care about a lot of stuff.

Comment: @PhilDukhov Thank you so much! I had to update the compose compiler too, but that fixed it :)